# Is the html structure necessary in an .erb file in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I follow the Ruby on Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl and I'm stuck with an example that is not working for me.
I try to remove duplicate code from .erb files so that the code exists only in the application.html.erb file. With the old home.html.erb file everything works out well (when I do a GET for home the content is shown), but with the one I am supposed to use to eliminate duplicate code, no content is shown. After testing, I found out that even removing the title tag from the old file is enough to make the content dissapear.

Any ideas why that is happening? Is the tutorial wrong or did I miss something?

application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Title | <%= yield(:title) %></title>
  <title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>

<body>
<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

home.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'Home') %>
<h1>Sample App</h1>
<p>
This is the home page for the
<a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
sample application.
</p>
```

old home.html.erb:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Home') %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title | <%= yield(:title) %></title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Sample App</h1>
<p>
This is the home page for the
<a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
sample application.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's your `home.html.erb` for? Is it a layout?

Comment: Can you show the controller?

Comment: my home.html.erb is a view, the application.html.erb is my layout.

Comment: my controller is the following 

`class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def help
  end

  def about
  end
end`

Comment: I am confused what the actual question is here.

Comment: the question is why doesn't the content of the new home.html.erb file appear when I do a GET request on home. With the old file, it did!

Comment: Why do you have two title tags, one left open, in your layout file?

Comment: that was the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your layout file is that you have two `<title>` tags, one containing the title of your application, and one left open. If you remove the one left open, the problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You should fill in the application layout in the controller. In other words, add  `layout 'application'` to your controller. For example:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
    layout 'application'

    def home 
    end 

    def help 
    end

    def about 
    end 
end
```

Comment: I did that but it was not enough